# Expanding UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to expand a UITableViewCell to reveal more content. So far i've got the animation down, but my problem is the new content appears before the animation is complete. Here is my code:

ps the description label and read button both start off as hidden when the cell is configured.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedRow = indexPath;
    SDJCell *cell = (SDJCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    cell.descriptionLabel.hidden = NO;
    cell.readButton.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SDJCell *cell = (SDJCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    cell.descriptionLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.readButton.hidden = YES;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(selectedRow && indexPath.row == selectedRow.row) {
    return 100;
    }
    return 44;
}
```

Any ideas for how I can reveal this extra content after the cell is done expanding??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. The solution is to set the autoresizing mask of the cell, so that it resizes along with its superview.

```
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

you could also do this in sotoryboard, both flags can be set under identity inspector

Comment: did you by chance find a way to shrink the cell back on a second touch? I'm trying to figure out a way to undo the effect

Comment: Yes, just set the height back to the minimum height and it should do it.

Comment: what if ur cell has a dynamic height from the start?