# iOS: Xcode - How to reveal content from under a cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, nstablecellview

I'm trying to create an app similar to the one in the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhi5Z.jpg

It looks like a table view with contents revealed under the cell on tap. Does anyone know how to do this. I've managed to to create a cell that have the content I want to reveal and restrict the height of the cell when the table is loaded. On tap the height just increases. But this is not how I want it. Also the content to be revealed could be of any height so i need to resize the cell accordingly.

Perhaps there is another way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Ok I've got this to work to an extent but there are certain issues with this:
1) Some of the rows just show the data from previous rows
2) Expanding and Collapsing the cell changes content, when it should just show/hide

My code:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "Data.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController {
        NSArray *data;
        NSInteger selectedIndex;
        NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        selectedIndex = -1;

        self.navigationItem.title = @"Test App";

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
        [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

        // Create Data array
        Data *data1 = [Data new];
        data1.text = @"Abhijit ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data1.translation = @"AbhijitDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data2 = [Data new];
        data2.text = @"Anurag ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data2.translation = @"AnuragDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data3 = [Data new];
        data3.text = @"Chetan ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data3.translation = @"ChetanDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data4 = [Data new];
        data4.text = @"Eric ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data4.translation = @"EricDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data5 = [Data new];
        data5.text = @"Neha ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsumiraj dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data5.translation = @"NehaDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data6 = [Data new];
        data6.text = @"Nilesh ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data6.translation = @"NileshDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data7 = [Data new];
        data7.text = @"Niraj ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsumiraj dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data7.translation = @"NirajDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, nil];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return data.count;
    }

    // This just a convenience function to get the height of the label based on the comment text
    -(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForIndex:(NSString *)string
    {
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 10000);

        CGSize labelHeightSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        return labelHeightSize.height + 10;

    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UILabel *mainLabel, *secondLabel;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            // First label
            mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 36.00)];
            mainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
            mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            mainLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            // mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            // mainLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

            // Second label
            secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 320.0, 36.00)];
            secondLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
            secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            // secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            // secondLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];
        }

        // Get data for the current row
        Data *dataContent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        CGFloat dataTextHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.text];

        mainLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, dataTextHeight);
        mainLabel.text = dataContent.text;

        CGFloat dataTranslationHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.translation];

        secondLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, dataTextHeight + 10.00, 320.0, dataTranslationHeight);
        secondLabel.text = dataContent.translation;

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            secondLabel.hidden = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            secondLabel.hidden = YES;
        }

        return cell;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Get data for the current row
        Data *dataContent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        CGFloat dataTextHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.text];
        CGFloat dataTranslationHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.translation];

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            return (dataTextHeight + dataTranslationHeight) + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return dataTextHeight;
        }
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // An expanded cell is clicked, minimize it
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            selectedIndex = -1;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            return;
        }

        // If any previous cell is expanded, minimize it
        if(selectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

        // Expand the currently expanded cell
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        NSIndexPath *currentPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:currentPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: What kind of "reveal" do you want?  The covering view fades away, the revealed item slides in, or ???

Comment: well... basically i'm coding an indian local language translation app... and basically need to show the english statements in a tabular view... tapping on any row should slide the translation from under the cell... tapping it once more should slide the translation back up... the content of each row and translation can be of any length, which mean the size of the row and the translation should be dynamic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out.

Here's my updated code if anyone needs it:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "Data.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController {
        NSArray *data;
        NSInteger selectedIndex;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        selectedIndex = -1;

        self.navigationItem.title = @"Test App";

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
        [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

        // Create Data array
        Data *data1 = [Data new];
        data1.text = @"Abhijit ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data1.translation = @"AbhijitDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data2 = [Data new];
        data2.text = @"Anurag ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data2.translation = @"AnuragDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data3 = [Data new];
        data3.text = @"Chetan ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data3.translation = @"ChetanDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data4 = [Data new];
        data4.text = @"Eric ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data4.translation = @"EricDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data5 = [Data new];
        data5.text = @"Neha ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsumiraj dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data5.translation = @"NehaDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data6 = [Data new];
        data6.text = @"Nilesh ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data6.translation = @"NileshDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        Data *data7 = [Data new];
        data7.text = @"Niraj ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsumiraj dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        data7.translation = @"NirajDE ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

        data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, nil];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return data.count;
    }

    -(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForIndex:(NSString *)string
    {
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 10000);
        CGSize labelHeightSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        return labelHeightSize.height + 10;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        static const int mainLabelTag = 1, secondLabelTag = 2;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            // First label
            UILabel *mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 36.00)];
            mainLabel.tag = mainLabelTag;
            mainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
            mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            mainLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            // mainLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

            // Second label
            UILabel *secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 320.0, 36.00)];
            secondLabel.tag = secondLabelTag;
            secondLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
            secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            secondLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            // secondLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];
        }

        // Get data for the current row
        Data *dataContent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        CGFloat dataTextHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.text];

        UILabel *mainLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:mainLabelTag];
        CGRect mainLabelFrame = mainLabel.frame;
        mainLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, mainLabelFrame.size.width, dataTextHeight);
        mainLabel.text = dataContent.text;

        CGFloat dataTranslationHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.translation];

        UILabel *secondLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:secondLabelTag];
        CGRect secondLabelFrame = mainLabel.frame;
        secondLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, dataTextHeight + 10.00, secondLabelFrame.size.width, dataTranslationHeight);
        secondLabel.text = dataContent.translation;

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            secondLabel.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            secondLabel.hidden = YES;
        }

        return cell;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Get data for the current row
        Data *dataContent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CGFloat dataTextHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.text];
        CGFloat dataTranslationHeight = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:dataContent.translation];

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            return (dataTextHeight + dataTranslationHeight) + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return dataTextHeight;
        }
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
        // An expanded cell is clicked, minimize it
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            selectedIndex = -1;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            return;
        }

        // If any previous cell is expanded, minimize it
        if(selectedIndex > -1)
        {
            NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
            selectedIndex = -1;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }

        // Expand the currently expanded cell
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        NSIndexPath *currentPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:currentPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically sized cells are a pain in the butt and then some. Look it up because there's a bunch of questions on it on StackOverflow with some interesting solutions.

As far as an underside view is concerned, there's a great open source project called [HHPanningTableViewCell](https://github.com/gloubibou/HHPanningTableViewCell) that you should look into. We've used for a couple of our projects and it does the trick. Unfortunately there's some performance issues (see my open issue on the project) so make sure that you test it on a device.

Comment: Nice contribution, thanks for letting us know about HHPanningTableViewCell.  Jim

Comment: this seems pretty neat... not what i require at the moment, but definitely something i can use in the future...

Answer (score 0):

In the table view delegate `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, use the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` methods to insert a new cell when the 'source language' cell is tapped, with the inserted cell being the 'destination language'.  When the user taps again, delete the 'destination language' cell.  In both methods, the reveal animation you wish can be specified.

Comment: thanks... i used `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to just reload the row to show the hidden label content... but i came across some issues... please see my code above...

Answer (score -1):

maybe try something like

```
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

?

Comment: Cells aren't resized in this way. You need to override the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: i know, and you will obviously have to override this method either way, but this way (combination) it'd be possible to change it more easily. Look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220565/expanding-uitableviewcell and please double check before voting down answers

Comment: i think i've tried this before... i'll try posting the source code here or even the project for reference...

Comment: adding these bits of code actually causes some issues... i've commented in my code above...